# Hourglass in C++ adding arguments

Tags: c++, loops, iostream

I've been dealing with creating a hourglass on the console in C++ for the past few hours and I've created a code which should logically work but in reality it doesn't.

When I try to run the code it asks me the height of the hourglass like it should. But then, after I input it, the result is a infinite list of "0" which is definetly not what i expected.

I also need to add the arguments to this code but I don't really know how, so if you could please help me you'd do me a favour.

Here it's the code i did (not properly working):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int height, base, distance, jeg, backup1, backup2, backup3;

    base = 2 * height - 1;
    distance = 1;
    jeg = base - 2;

    cout << "write the height";
    cin >> height;

    while (backup1 > 0)
    {
        cout << "0";
        backup1 = backup1--;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    height = height - 1;

    while (height > 1)
    {
        backup1 = distance;
        while (backup1 > 0)
        {
            cout << " ";
            backup1 = backup1--;
        }
        backup2 = jeg;
        while (backup2 > 0)
        {
            cout << "#";
            backup3 = backup3--;
        }
        cout << "\n";

        height = height--;
        distance = distance++;
        jeg = jeg - 2;
    }

    backup1 = distance;
    while (backup1 > 0)
    {
        cout << " ";
        backup1 = backup1--;
    }
    cout << "#\n";

    height = backup2 - 1;
    distance = distance--;
    jeg = jeg + 2;

    while (height > 1)
    {
        backup1 = distance;
        while (backup1 > 0)
        {
            cout << " ";
            backup1 = backup1--;
        }
        backup2 = jeg;
        while (backup2 > 0)
        {
            cout << "#";
            backup3 = backup3--;
        }
        height = height--;
        distance = distance--;
        jeg = jeg + 2;
    }

    backup1 = base;

    while (backup1 > 0)
    {
        cout << "#";
        backup1 = backup1--;
    }
    cout << "\n";

}
```

**Edit #1:** sorry for not being clear.
I expected something like this at the end of the run:

```
#############
 ###########
  #########
   #######
    #####
     ###
      #
     ###
    #####
   #######
  #########
 ###########
#############
```

Comment: Why `backup = backup--;` instead of plain `backup--`;

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That's even worse than you think, because it leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Looks good, thanks @Jan :)

Comment: @NathanOliver i actually used an online compiler. did i have to use something else?

Comment: @january_feelings, yes, a proper IDE and debugger. A *good debugger* is perhaps more needed than a good compiler.

Comment: `backup1` is not initialized ...

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis ooo okay maybe this is why i had that result. do you think so?

Comment: @january_feelings lots of code issues are way clearer when you simply step with a debugger, rathern than looking at 100s (if not 10000s) of code desperately to find the issue, let alone the more advanced features that a debugger provides.

Comment: thank u so much @MichaelChourdakis

Comment: @Damien what should i add to the code to initialize it?

Comment: @january_feelings How many "0" do you want to write? For example, `backup1 = base;`

Answer (score 3):

First, the following block is executed before `height` is inialized, and you need to move it after `cin>> height`:

```
base = 2 * height - 1;
distance = 1;
jeg = base - 2;
```

The next significant problem is that you loop on `backup1` which is not is not initialized. **Worse**: even if you would initialize it, **the following statement is a real problem**:

```
backup1 = backup1--;    // OUCH !!!
```

Why ? Because in the same statement you have two side effects on the same variable `backup1`:  the first is the decrement, and the second is the set the value before the decrement.  You need to chose:

```
backup1--;             // alternative 1
backup1 = backup1 -1;  // alternative 2
backup1 -= 1;          // alternative 3
```

And you need to remove all the similar constructs for `backup2` and `backup3`, `height` and `distance` (also with `distance++`)

Finally, you have an endless loop:

```
while(backup2>0) {   // you loop on backup2
   cout << "#";  
   backup3--;      // but it doesn't change since you decrement the wrong variable
}
```

Once you have done all these corrections,  it will work approxiamtely, at least for the first half of the hourglass.  I leave you as an exercise to complete the hourglass, now that you know what you should not do.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/0T9v1o)

---

**Important to know:**

Having two side effects on the same variable in the same expression is undefined behavior according to `[intro.execution]/10` in para 6.8.1 of the standard:

> If a side effect on a memory location is **unsequenced** relative
>   to either another side effect on the same memory location or a value
>   computation using the value of any object in the same memory location,
>   and they are not potentially concurrent, the behavior is
>   undefined.

In your case, it's slightly different, since according to `[expr.ass]/1` in para 8.5.18:

> In all cases, the assignment is **sequenced after** the value computation
>   of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of
>   the assignment expression.

So in your case, it's not UB, but it's simply that your statement ensures that the decrement is ignored because of the postfix.

Comment: +1 for the dedication in getting OP's original to a working state using *their* algorithm. I would've told them to scrap it and start over, so kudos for this.

Comment: It is also important that OP's use of `backup1 = backup1--;` is only well-defined since C++17. It they are compiling for e.g. C++14, then it will still be undefined behavior (since your second quote wasn't there before C++17). I am also unsure that all compilers implement the C++17 order of evaluation rule changes completely at the moment.

Comment: @walnut your are completely right.  I confess that I hesitated when I was writing my answer and I almost wrote UB, but I preferred to cross check.  C++11 and C++14 both show the example `i=i++ + 1` as undefined in section 1.9.  But we have to live with our time and C++17 now shows the same example with a defined behavior and show `i=i++ + i` as undefined because both sides of the + operator are indeterminely sequenced.

Answer (score 1):

There is **a lot** wrong with your code. To start with:

```
int ..., backup1, ...;

while(backup1 > 0) {
    cout << "0";
    backup1 = backup1--;
}
```

What's the value of `backup1` there? The answer is garbage! This is Undefined Behavior, so the value in `backup1` could be any integer!! So it's no wonder you're seeing a whole bunch of `0`'s!

But assuming we fix that, doing maybe something like `int backup1 = 5;`, `backup = backup--;` is also undefined behavior!!

Little errors like these are all over your code ([@Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59618726/2602718) does a good job of talking through them in their answer). As such, I'd strongly suggest you scrap this and rewrite it. Let me give you some hints to make it easier though...

---

You've got a good start, you've realized that the top and bottom of the hourglass will be `2 * height - 1`. That's good. My first tip for you is to stop trying to print a single sharp at a time. You can create a string with some number of the same character very easily, use that!

For example, since you know how many sharps are in the first row, you could output it with:

```
int num_sharps = 2*height - 1;
int num_spaces = 0;
std::cout << std::string(num_spaces, ' ')
          << std::string(num_sharps, '#')
          << std::endl
```

This will output `num_spaces` number of spaces followed by `num_sharps` number of sharps and then a newline. Viola!

And now the next line you need to print will have two less sharps than that and one more space, so update those values accordingly and run the output line again!

With this, you should be able to very easily and cleanly produce your hourglass (though you may need a second loop for the other half!).

And as a bonus just for fun, [here's a full solution](https://ideone.com/gP1gks) in just a few lines, just to show that with enough math, anything is possible :D

Answer (score 0):

You should get a warning here:

```
int height, base, distance, jeg, backup1, backup2, backup3;

base = 2 * height - 1;
distance = 1;
jeg = base - 2;
```

for using `height` when it is uninitialized. You need to first take user input, then use the value not the other way around. After that anything can happen. Using `base` here and later in the code invokes undefined behaviour. Also `backup1 = backup1--;` is definitely not doing what you think it does.

To print a certain character, eg `'#'`, `n`-times you can use

```
std::cout << std::string(n,'#');
```

In a loop you can write:

```
for (int i=0;i< height*2 + 1; ++i) {
    auto empty = height - std::abs( height - i);
    std::cout << std::string(empty,' ') << "x\n";    
}
```

to get for `height == 6`:

```
x
 x
  x
   x
    x
     x
    x
   x
  x
 x
x
```

From here its just a small step to fill the hourglass:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    int height;
    std::cin >> height;

    for (int i=0;i< height*2 + 1; ++i) {
        auto empty = height - std::abs( height - i);
        auto fill = 2*(height-empty)+1;
        std::cout << std::string(empty,' ') << std::string(fill,'x') << "\n";    
    }
}
```

Comment: Good start!  What about the many `xxx = xxx--;` ? And the assignement of xxx to the value before xxx is decremented ?

Comment: @Christophe in progress

Answer (score 0):

Hard as always getting into the mechanisms of someone else's code, especially when not commented.
I wrote a brand new code hoping it could help. Here is it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int height, spaces = 0, nextLayer;
    do
    {
        cout << "Insert the height of the hourglass: ";
        cin >> height;
    }while(height > 0 && height%2 == 0); //Loop into asking a valid height

    nextLayer = height; //First layer has the same number of # as there are number of layers, aka height

    //First loop for the top part of the hourglass
    for(int c = 0; c < height/2 + 1; c++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < spaces; k++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < nextLayer; k++)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl; //end the line
        nextLayer = nextLayer - 2; //Decrease the number of #
        spaces++; //Augment the indentation
    }

    /*
    ** Since we are now going to make the bottom specular part
    ** let's "come back" by two loops
    */
    nextLayer = nextLayer + 4;
    spaces = spaces - 2;

    //Second loop for the bottom part of the hourglass
    for(int c = 0; c < height/2; c++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < spaces; k++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < nextLayer; k++)
        {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
        nextLayer = nextLayer + 2;
        spaces--;
    }
}
```